# Execute proc step only if it doesn't cause log error (inside macro) SAS

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I'm trying to test different covariance structures inside macro with Proc Mixed.

```
%macro cov(type);
proc mixed data=tmp order=data;
class sub trt visit;
model var = trt visit trt*visit / S cl;
repeated visit  /subject=sub type=&type.; 
FitStatistics=min_var_&type.;   
run;
%mend;
```

Some of the covariance structures I need to fit in model causes errors and I'm trying to find a way to execute this proc mixed statement only, if it doesn't cause error with value of &type.

I have been working with %sysfunc and but haven't been able to resolve this yet.

```
%IF %SYSFUNC(EXIST(min_var_&type.)) %THEN %DO;
data help_&type.;
set min_var_&type.;
run;
%end;
```

This produces these datasets correctly, but still log errors exists in log for those macro variables that can not be fitted.

Comment: Why do some of the covariance structures cause errors?  Is this something you can predict before running `PROC MIXED`?  You can't tell `PROC MIXED` to only run if it won't cause errors, but you can control what happens after that error occurs.  But I think better would be to not have errors, so perhaps start by addressing that, either yourself or address it in the question, preferably with some example data that shows the kind of errors you mean.

Comment: I'm running this macro for multiple datasets and for some of them specific covariance structure fits and for others, it doesn't. And before fitting proc mixed, I can't tell what kind of covariance sturcture fits for that data.

Comment: If your goal is to avoid error messages in your log, and you can't predict when PROC MIXED will throw an error, you could redirect the log using PROC PRINTTO, then run MIXED, redirect back to the main log, then test if the alternative log had errors or not, and decide whether or not to run that model in again.

Comment: @Laura So what happens in PROC MIXED if the covariance structure doesn't fit?  Does the proc error?  If so, what actually is causing the error?

Comment: 'QUANEW Optimization cannot be completed.  ' So i guess that kind of covariance structure simply doesn't fit to that specific data while other it might fit and that's why it has to be fitted anyway.

Comment: The point asking this question was to find out if I can run macro for specific variable only if it won't cause errors, but based on answers I'll think that's impossible (except modifying log file).  But thanks anyway for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect the log to a file like that :

```
filename logfile "\\SERVER\LOG\mylog.log";

    proc printto log=logfile new;
    run;
```

And then when your PROC MIXED is finished, you can filter on the log file for the string "ERROR" :

```
....YOUR PROC MIXED...

/*come back to normal log*/
    proc printto;
    run;

/*check the log file*/
    DATA CHECKLOG;
            LENGTH ROWS $200;
            LABEL ROWS = 'Messages from LOG';
            INFILE "\\SERVER\LOG\mylog.log" TRUNCOVER;
            INPUT ROWS &;
            LINE = _N_;

            IF SUBSTR(ROWS,1,5)='ERROR' /*OR SUBSTR(ROWS,1,7)='WARNING'*/ THEN

            OUTPUT;
    RUN;
```

You will have all the ERROR and (or WARNING if needed) in a dataset.

Then you have to check if the table is empty.
If YES, you can continue your script.

You can do it via this method

```
proc sql;
select * from checklog;
run;
%put n=&sqlobs;
```

If sqlobs is greater than 0, then you have errors.
You can check the sqlobs via a macro function like this :

```
%macro checklog;
    proc sql;
    select * from checklog;
    run;

%if (&sqlobs>0) %then ...
%else ...

%mend checklog;
```